# Rotation animation around an elements origin to C# code

Tags: c#, wpf, xaml

I have a XAML code which animates the angle property of an element's rotatetransform:

```
<Canvas.RenderTransform>
                        <RotateTransform Angle="0" 
                                         x:Name="MyAnimatedTransform"/>
                    </Canvas.RenderTransform>
                    <Canvas.Triggers>
                        <EventTrigger RoutedEvent="Loaded">
                            <BeginStoryboard>
                                <Storyboard>
                                    <DoubleAnimation                 Storyboard.TargetName="MyAnimatedTransform"
                                                     Storyboard.TargetProperty="(RotateTransform.Angle)"
                                                     From="0.0"
                                                     To="90"
                                                     Duration="0:0:1" />
                                </Storyboard>
                            </BeginStoryboard>
                        </EventTrigger>
                    </Canvas.Triggers>
```

I've been trying ever since to convert this to C# code, but for some reason I think I'm missing something...

**Code:**

```
   public void AnimateElement(RotateTransform element, UIElement control, double degreesTo, double secDuration)
        {
            DoubleAnimation OriginAnimatorDoubleAnimation = new DoubleAnimation()
            {
                From = 0,
                To = degreesTo,
                Duration = TimeSpan.FromSeconds(secDuration)
            };

            Storyboard.SetTargetProperty(element, new PropertyPath("RotateTransform.Angle"));
            Storyboard.SetTarget(element, OriginAnimatorDoubleAnimation);

            Storyboard storyboard = new Storyboard();
            storyboard.Duration = TimeSpan.FromSeconds(secDuration);
            storyboard.Children.Add(OriginAnimatorDoubleAnimation);

            storyboard.Begin();
        }
```

Could someone tell me what I'm doing wrong?

Thanks,

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This is not an exact equivalent of you XAML, but you don't need a Storyboard in code behind.

```
public void RotateElement(UIElement element, double degreesTo, double secDuration)
{
    if (element.RenderTransform is RotateTransform transform)
    {
        var animation = new DoubleAnimation
        {
            To = degreesTo,
            Duration = TimeSpan.FromSeconds(secDuration)
        };

        transform.BeginAnimation(RotateTransform.AngleProperty, animation);
    }
}
```

Note that there still must already be a RotateTransform in the RenderTransform of the element. If that is not the case, this will put it in place:

```
public void RotateElement(UIElement element, double degreesTo, double secDuration)
{
    var transform = element.RenderTransform as RotateTransform;

    if (transform == null)
    {
        transform = new RotateTransform();
        element.RenderTransform = transform;
        element.RenderTransformOrigin = new Point(0.5, 0.5);
    }

    var animation = new DoubleAnimation
    {
        To = degreesTo,
        Duration = TimeSpan.FromSeconds(secDuration)
    };

    transform.BeginAnimation(RotateTransform.AngleProperty, animation);
}
```

Comment: As I wrote, there must be a RotateTransform in `element.RenderTransform` before using the first code snippet. Otherwise, use the second one.

Answer (score 0):

This worked for me:

```
  public void RotateElement(RotateTransform transform, double degreesTo, double secDuration)
        {
            var animation = new DoubleAnimation
            {
                To = degreesTo,
                Duration = TimeSpan.FromSeconds(secDuration)
            };

            transform.BeginAnimation(RotateTransform.AngleProperty, animation);

        }
```

Thanks though!